# Ktor Android Client Websocket Connection Failed

Tags: kotlin, websocket, ktor

The WebSocket server is a online testing one
[The Website](http://coolaf.com/tool/chattest)
Something goes wrong And I don't know how to fix it.

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) { install(WebSockets) }
GlobalScope.launch {
    client.webSocket("ws://82.157.123.54:9010/ajaxchattest") {}
}
```

the error printStackTrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to parse request body: request body length 
should be specified,
chunked transfer encoding should be used or
keep-alive should be disabled (connection: close)
```

not knowing how to enable encoding or disable keep-alive or specify body length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `82.157.123.54:9010/ajaxchattest` endpoint responds with `403 Forbidden` instead of `101 Switching Protocols` if the `Origin` header is absent or invalid. So to make it work just append the `Origin` header with a well-formed value:

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) { install(WebSockets) }
client.webSocket("ws://82.157.123.54:9010/ajaxchattest", request = {
    header(HttpHeaders.Origin, "http://example")
}) {}
```